# Resin printer screen damage?

Tags: resin, lcd-screen, anycubic-photon

After an incident that caused a hole in the FEP and resin leakage, the screen now gives the same dark right side for all 3 test patterns. You can faintly see it split into 3 other sections but not as dark. It will not even attempt to print a file- just the same thing as the test patterns during every light cycle.

There may or may not have been a piece of support or something in there that put pressure on the screen, but there are no visible cracks.

Usually my screens fail differently. The clearly delimited sections of varying light brightness are a mystery.

I'm thinking this is the screen and not the controller board or something else that is bad... Thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same with my Anycubic Photon. It was the screen itself that started delaminating and the contacts coming loose from the resin.
Replaced the screen and it fixed the issue.